# flex-direction and flex not working for all browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox

I've following CSS class and I want to make it work for all below browsers:

1. IE 9 and above
2. Chrome
3. Mozilla Firefox
4. Safari

   ```
   .itemContainer {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
   }
   .wrap-vertical {
          flex: 1;
          margin-top: 15px;
   }
   ```

Currently it is only working on Chrome and FF.

And I tried `-ms-` and `-webkit-` for IE and Safari but it's not working.

Please suggest changes to accommodate this.

Comment: Check browser support. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

IE 9 *does not* support flexbox.

IE 10 supports an old flexbox specification and requires [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Although Safari 9 supports the current flexbox spec without prefixes, older versions require prefixes.

For a complete review of flexbox browser support, see this page:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).